# MVC Encrypt information according to the user's role

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Can someone help Encrypt information according to the user's role?
Basically I want the following: if the User Role = "Admin" the mobile phone number (Telemovel) appears 435267456. If the User Role = "User" the number of the mobile phone appears (Telemovel) xxxxxxxxxx.

I have used this   @if (User.IsInRole("Admin")) to hide links depending on the role and it works, now I want to encrypt the information.

**Model**

```
public partial class Cliente
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public Cliente()
    {
        this.Reserva = new HashSet<Reserva>();
    }

    public int ID_Cliente { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public string Morada { get; set; }
    public string Telemovel { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Contribuinte { get; set; }
    public string CartaoCidadao { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime DataValidade { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime DataNascimento { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime DataRegisto { get; set; }
    public string País { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Reserva> Reserva { get; set; }
}
```

**View example**

```
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Telemóvel</label>
        <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
            <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-earphone"></i></span>
                <input name="Telemovel" class="form-control" type="text" value="@Model.Telemovel" readonly="readonly">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: It is just for display purposes ? Then "masking" is a more appropriate term to use. In your action method, check the user is in specific role and then set the phone number property of your view model to `xxxxxxxxxx` and send to the view. This is only for display purpose. Make sure your code is not updating this value back to the database. ( Using view models will help up to an extent in that case)

Comment: @Shyju that´s it. But, how i can do it?